# In Firebird would be a way to auto-update coincident rows in a INSERT procedure?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.1

if you are running a query that inserts a new set of records in a table from other one, there is a way to force the update of the coincident pk record in the destination table, without deleting records or split the process in two others (insert new and update existing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebird 2.1, you can do [Update or Insert](http://www.firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rlsnotes210.html#rnfb210-updorinsrt)

```
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO T1 (F1, F2)
    VALUES (:F1, :F2)
    MATCHING (F1);
```

Comment: Sorry, i'll be more objective:

Comment: I receive a large txt file containing csv non normalized data everyday. This file contains new and updated data, wich with I insert/update a database. I must to update the records referent data already existing and insert the new ones. Example: I must delete yesterday's records, reinsert the updated values for them and insert the today's new records, from same txt file. I wonder if would be a way to do this two operations in a single step, like eg. forcing the update of the data if occours pk constraint violation. If we don't have a sql/built-in way, maybe a stored procedure can do it...?

Comment: The link I send you explain how to do this : I understand finally well